# How to remove substrings from column rows if substrings aren't part of dictionary's values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simplified DataFrame:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | A, B, C, D |

I create a dictionary d:

```
d = {'foo': 'A, B, C'}
```

Dictionary keys are in column A and their values are in column B. How can I remove any substrings that aren't part of my dictionary's values?

Desired DataFrame:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | A, B, C |

Comment: Please show us a real example of your data. This is so ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need compare by spiltted values by `,`  use:

```
d = {'foo': 'A, B, C'}

f = lambda x: ', '.join(y for y in x.B.split(', ') if y in x.A.split(', '))
df['B'] = df.assign(A = df['A'].map(d)).apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
     A        B
0  foo  A, B, C
```